Reverse nginx SSL to Azure MySQL Flexible server in docker not working as expected
I am running into an issue with my application that currently does not support SSL for the database connection.
Unfortunately this will require that I turn off the require_secure_transport parameter which is unacceptable.
Since I am already using nginx to proxy incoming requests to my application using uwsgi, I thought maybe to have database requests from my application proxying through nginx and nginx could handle the encryption. Unfortunately this part is not working and requests to MySQL are timing out.
This is my docker compose:
services:
  web2py:
    build: web2py_copy/
    image: web2py
    command: uwsgi
    environment:
      - WEB2PY_PASSWORD=password
      - CONN_STR=mysql://user:password@nginx:3306/test
    volumes:
      - ./web2py_copy/web2py:/opt/web2py
    networks:
      - web2py
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/sites-available/web2py.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/conf.d/web2py:/etc/nginx/conf.d/web2py:ro
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./web2py_copy/web2py:/opt/web2py:ro
    depends_on:
      - web2py
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 8443:443
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - web2py

networks:
  web2py:

and this is my nginx.conf file:
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

stream {

    server {
        listen 3306;

        proxy_pass test.mysql.database.azure.com:3306;

        ssl_preread on;
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA;
    }
}

The DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem certificate is from here and is required to connect securely to Azure MySQL Flexible Server.
If I disable require_secure_transport and remove the ssl_ options in the nginx config then I can connect to the database through nginx.
Basically I am left with this:
stream {
    server {
        listen 3306;
        proxy_pass test.mysql.database.azure.com:3306;
    }
}

Using the ssl_ options in nginx causes the db connection to timeout regardless of require_secure_transport
To summarize:
This is what I am trying to accomplish and am failing:
My app --unencrypted--> nginx --encrypted with digicert--> azure mysql

Your setup attempts to proxy MySQL connections through Nginx, encrypting traffic between Nginx and Azure MySQL. However, the issue may be rooted in how Nginx handles SSL for database traffic and the SSL prerequisites required by Azure.
Here are some troubleshooting suggestions and improvements to ensure the connection works:

Nginx SSL Handshake Requirements

Azure MySQL enforces SSL-based connections with certain SSL settings that might not be fully satisfied by your current configuration.
Try modifying the ssl_protocols and ssl_ciphers to match Azure's requirements, and ensure Nginx is correctly handling the certificates. You may need to adjust the ssl_verify_client and ssl_preread directives:
stream {
    server {
        listen 3306;

        proxy_pass test.mysql.database.azure.com:3306;

        ssl_preread on;  # Required for SSL database connections

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/your_cert.pem;  # Your certificate (if client-side cert is needed)
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/your_key.pem;  # Private key
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem;  # DigiCert for Azure MySQL

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;  # Adjust depth if needed
    }
}


Verify SSL Handshake with Azure
You may be able to test whether the SSL handshake works outside Nginx using the openssl tool. Run the following command inside your Docker container:

openssl s_client -connect test.mysql.database.azure.com:3306 -CAfile /etc/nginx/ssl/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem

This will confirm whether the certificate chain is properly set up.

Possible Workaround for Timeout
The ssl_preread directive is necessary for protocols like MySQL when proxying SSL connections in Nginx. However, it can also interfere with how Nginx handles SSL. You can try commenting it out to see if this impacts your timeout issue:

stream {
    server {
        listen 3306;
        proxy_pass test.mysql.database.azure.com:3306;
        #ssl_preread on;  # Disable to test
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    }
}


Check Nginx Logs
Look at the Nginx logs for detailed error messages (/var/log/nginx/error.log). There may be SSL handshake errors or connection timeouts that provide more specific reasons for failure.

Timeout Settings
You may also want to add timeout settings to ensure Nginx gives adequate time for SSL connections:


stream {
    server {
        listen 3306;

        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_timeout 30s;
        proxy_pass test.mysql.database.azure.com:3306;

        ssl_preread on;
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    }
}


Test Database Access with SSL Disabled
Confirm that the connection works by disabling SSL in your Nginx config. This ensures that the MySQL connection is functional and the problem lies only with SSL:

stream {
    server {
        listen 3306;
        proxy_pass test.mysql.database.azure.com:3306;
    }
}

Once you've isolated the issue, you can re-enable SSL with adjustments. Let me know how these steps work out!
